# HTML website design, links opening smaller windows on the page

Tags: javascript, html, window

So i tried searching for what I looked for but I couldn't really find exactly what I was looking for, if it even is possible that is.

What I'm looking for is a way to make the links people click on my website appear almost as ads, not a seperate window or tab in the browser but its own small window on the current tab itself. I made a image as a sort of example of what I mean. I don't know if it'll do any good but its worth a shot, I'd love to have it be able to work with Coolmenu as well. And if people wanted to open them in a new window or new tab, they could just right click, like below:

[image: screenshot]

Update: 10:32 7.11
I realized that both of these links, as well as when i searched for some on my own all date form like 2006-2009, whereas all of them use

```
<div id="overlay">
<div>
<p>Content you want the user to see goes here.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I think I can just write () (correct me if im wrong) as well as the paragraph stuff, but what should I do about all the ? should I just straight out remove it or replace it?

Update 10:50 7.11
I don't got more time to work on it today but next time I got some time, should I post all the other javascript and css I have on my page (only coolmenu that is) to give you some sort of idea of what exactly I want to accomplish?
And again, thank you all for the great help.

Update 12.11 08:05: I'm having trouble getting it to work together with Coolmenu. 
I can provide with my css and javascript code for both coolmenu and the window thing if required, should i upload a .txt or just put it here?

Comment: Since you don't want to open a window, you need to be looking into making your own 'JavaScript Prompt' I shouldn't imagine anybody would want to just make this script and give it to you because it will take some work. Search "Custom JavaScript Prompt" on google.

Comment: What you describe is a called "modal window", there are a few libraries for this out there. Usually you can't open those in a new tab, but that would just be a matter of preventing the default action on a link and open the modal on a click, so right click still works.

Comment: @kapep +1 I just learnt something.

Answer (score 2):

#### Modal Windows

I guess you wanna make **Modal Windows**. You can easily do that using this tutorial here: [Simple jQuery Modal Window Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial).

#### Screenshot:

[image: Simple Modal Window]

#### Demo here: [Demo](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html)

---

#### jQuery Dialog

Or you can even use [**jQuery Dialogs**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), which uses same principle, but easy to implement.

[image: jQuery Dialog]

Comment: I'll check out both the answers you gave me and see what works out best for me, thank you very much. Would it be able to work with Coolmenu?

Comment: I realized that both of these links, as well as when i searched for some on my own all date form like 2006-2009, whereas all of them use <div and such, I've been told it's not needed at all for html 5, should i just remove div or are there various things I need to replace with something entirely different?

<div id="overlay">
     <div>
          <p>Content you want the user to see goes here.</p>
     </div>
</div>
I think I can just write <id="overlay"> (correct me if im wrong) as well as the paragraph stuff, but what should I do about all the <div>? should I just straight out remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't want to open a new window, this is the quickest way you will get it to work how you want and involves the least amount of javascript.

Code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open ('http://google.com', 'mywindow','location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=100,height=100');">Hi</a>
```

Parameter 1 is the URL, parameter 2 is the name of the window.

In the 3rd parameter you can pass the following options:

- **status**:  The status bar at the bottom of the window.
- **toolbar**: The standard browser toolbar, with buttons such as Back and Forward.
- **location**:    The Location entry field where you enter the URL.
- **menubar**: The menu bar of the window
- **directories**: The standard browser directory buttons, such as What’s New and What’s Cool
- **resizable**:   Allow/Disallow the user to resize the window.
- **scrollbars**:  Enable the scrollbars if the document is bigger than the window
- **height**:  Specifies the height of the window in pixels. (example:
  height=’350′)
- **width**:   Specifies the width of the window in pixels.

[For more info click here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Comment: They don't want to have a new window open.